# Logic Inference, Steps & Reasons

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Going from ¬(¬q → s) to ¬q ∧ ¬s, I am confused. Is this using expression for implication, double negation and DeMorgan's? The following is what I thought:

I thought first in terms of the rule that q → s ⇔ ¬q ∨ s

Then with the original negation on the q back in 
¬q → s ⇔ q ∨ s

Then with the original negation outside premises back in
⇔ ¬(q ∨ s)

Then DeMorgan's Law
⇔ ¬q ∧ ¬s

I feel that I'm making things more complicated then they need to be.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Another way - of course - is via truth table. A third way is with a derivation in *natural deduction*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct:

$$\begin{align} \lnot (\lnot p \rightarrow s)&\iff \lnot(\lnot(\lnot p) \lor s)\tag{1}\\\\ & \iff \lnot (p \lor s)\tag{2}\\\\ & \iff \lnot p \land \lnot s\tag{3}\end{align}$$

and for the reasons you give: $(1)$ by the definition of $\rightarrow$, $(2)$  double negation, and $(3)$ by applying DeMorgan's. Note that each step represents a *biconditional*, meaning that the implications go *both* directions.

It's not terribly complicated; you'll likely encounter far more complicated proofs using rules of replacement as well as proofs using rules of inference.